# how-to build openMax library on windows embedded device

Tags: assembly, arm, windows-ce, openmax

I'm trying to build OpenMax with neon optimizations on windows embedded compact 7( Armv7 with NEON is supported). At this moment I have a problem with this error:

```
Error   1   error A2003: improper line syntax: .    c:\Cortex-A8\vc\m4p10\src\omxVCM4P10_TransformDequantLumaDCFromPair_s.s 66  OpenMaxLibrary

line 66: dIn0                DN D0.S16
```

windows armasm.exe can't understand whats means ".S16"
anybody now any solution or another compatible compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Just for information. The ARM's NEON-based implementation of OpenMax DL API uses ARM assembler syntax that can be compiled by armasm tool from ARM compiler toolchain. There is a [community edition](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/ds-5/arm-compiler.php) of the toolchain available for free for individual contributors.